# Yii addInCondition with floats: How to ? and why addInCondition('column', array(1.1, 1.3)) don't work?

Tags: php, sql, yii

How to addInCondition with floats?

I tried a lot.

This works ok:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('order_id',array(36907));
$tasks=OrderTask::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

In my case it returns 4 models:

[image]

But if I try

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('order_id',array(36907));
$criteria->addInCondition('step',array(3.20));
$tasks=OrderTask::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Or

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('step',array("3.20"));
$tasks=OrderTask::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Or

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('step',array('3.2'));
$tasks=OrderTask::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Results are empty.

According to log, the query is:

> system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT * FROM `orders_tasks` `t` WHERE step=:ycp1. Bound with :ycp1=3.2)

This query in phpmyadmin returns 5360 rows

```
SELECT * FROM  `orders_tasks`  `t` WHERE step = 3.20
```

This queries in phpmyadmin returns 0 rows

```
SELECT * FROM  `orders_tasks`  `t` WHERE step = '3.20'
SELECT * FROM  `orders_tasks`  `t` WHERE step = '3.2'
SELECT * FROM  `orders_tasks`  `t` WHERE step = "3.20"
```

This try

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('step',array("3,20"));
$tasks=OrderTask::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

returns Models with step=3 OR 20

This query in phpmyadmin returns rows with step=3 OR 20

```
SELECT * FROM  `orders_tasks`  `t` WHERE step = '3,20'
```

So, how to `addInCondition` with floats?

## Details, for instance

`step` field is `float(8,2)`

Sql table dump:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_tasks` (
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `step` float(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `done` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
  KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
  KEY `step` (`step`),
  KEY `orderstep` (`order_id`,`step`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Yii version: 1.1.10

Comment: what kind of field is `step`? `varchar` or `decimal`?

Comment: @dInGd0nG it is float(6,2)

for instance:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_tasks` (
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `step` float(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `done` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
  KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
  KEY `step` (`step`),
  KEY `orderstep` (`order_id`,`step`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `orders_tasks`
--

INSERT INTO `orders_tasks` (`task_id`, `order_id`, `step`, `done`) VALUES
(1, 36907, 3.20, 0),
(2, 36907, 3.00, 0),
(3, 36907, 20.00, 0);

Comment: Add your code on the question, edit and paste there. That way anyone looking the question have all the needed information, don't need to read all the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `prefix_test`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prefix_test` (
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `step` float(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `done` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
  KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
  KEY `step` (`step`),
  KEY `orderstep` (`order_id`,`step`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


INSERT INTO `prefix_test` VALUES (1,36907,3.20,0);
INSERT INTO `prefix_test` VALUES (2,36907,3.21,0);
INSERT INTO `prefix_test` VALUES (3,37907,4.13,0);

$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('order_id',array(36907));
$criteria->addInCondition('step',array(3.20));
$tests=Test::model()->findAll($criteria);


echo "Rows: ".count($tests)."<br>";
#Returns Rows: 0
```

Query in Yii logs

```
SELECT * FROM `prefix_test` `t` WHERE (order_id=:ycp0) AND (step=:ycp1). Bound with :ycp0=36907, :ycp1=3.2
```

Real query in MySql logs

```
SELECT * FROM `prefix_test` `t` WHERE (order_id=36907) AND (step='3.2')
```

This will fix you problem

```
ALTER TABLE `prefix_test` CHANGE `step` `step` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL;
```

After that your query returns

```
#Returns Rows: 1
```

Comment: It works! So, fix is "change sql field type from float to decimal". Thank you.